# Show more categories button at end of Recyclerview(GridLayoutManager) like grofers app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Grofers app image

[image]

I want to add a show more categories button after 6 items in `recyclerview`, `onclick` of that show remaining items and show hide button at bottom

Comment: Try using an expandable animation, there is a good [one](https://github.com/freecats/TextViewExpandableAnimation) for textviews but I'm not sure if exists for recyclerview.

Comment: add **Footer** in `RecyclerView` and then `onclick` load more items. Its similar to load more functionality.

Comment: @Egek92 thank u for the reply . .I tried ur solution but i dont think we can use recyclerview like textviews

Comment: @VipulAsri thank u , i am able to add button in footer called show more , but my all data are coming from db, i.e if 25 data are coming , how i can limit only 6 to show , remaing to show onclick of button?

Comment: @NaveenNaik You can only pass 6 elements initially, then onclick of  submit button pass the remaining list and hide the button/footer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made a sample code for your situation: [RecyclerView-Grid-with-Load-More](https://gist.github.com/vipulasri/ae7fee8cc49677c02265c9827feef82e)

**Initial Screen**

[image: Intial Data]

**Updated Screen**

[image: Updated Data]

Comment: Thanx a lot ,It helped a lot

Comment: I have changed ur code acc. my requirement , i added hide button also, onclick of that show only first 6 items , it is working fine , but i am not able to change the Loadmore text dynamically. .  .i.e wen first time loadmore clicked it needs to change to see less .How can i achieve tat?

Comment: @NaveenNaik just provide `id` to textview in loadmore and access it like other views. Like how i did in elements recycler view and setText to textview.

Answer (score 0):

Initially add first 6 data to your Adapter and You need to create 2 Viewhoulder class for the Recyclerview

Eg :

//For all items

```
class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }
```

//For show more or End

```
class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}
```

In the getItemCount method return total data size + 1

```
  @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size() + 1;
        }
```

and in the Adapter return 1 for items at last item, otherwise 0

```
 @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            return data.size() == position +1 ? 1 : 0;      
  }
```

And from the onCreateViewHolder, you need to check the viewtype and return relevant Viewhoulder

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);//Normal item
             case 1: return new ViewHolder2(...); // End item
             ...
         }
    }
```

In the ViewHolder2(Load more button container) class set a onclicklister for the Load-more button and from it add the next 6 data to the adapter. After that call a `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: thank you for the help , but i am quite entry level , a bit more explanation or any code reference will be much more helpful . .